# vue cli service won't add new components to the library

Tags: vue.js, npm, vue-cli

I have a Vue project built with `vue cli` and I use `vue cli service` to make a component library from the project components. The problem is I have more than 20 components but only 2 of them are added to my npm package after I run this script:

```json
vue-cli-service build src/index.ts --target lib --name zwc --modern && rm ./dist/demo.html
```

```js
// src/index.ts
// This file used to build component by vue-cli-service

import { VueConstructor } from 'vue';
import * as components from './components';

const install = (Vue:VueConstructor) => {
  Object.entries(components).forEach(([name, component]) => {
    Vue.component(name, component);
  });
};

if (typeof window !== 'undefined' && window.Vue) {
  install(window.Vue);
}

export default install;
export * from './components';
```

In my nuxt project after I installed the package, I use it like this:

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import zwc from '@zarinpal/web-components';
import '@zarinpal/web-components/dist/zwc.css'

Vue.use(zwc)
```

Comment: How did you determine that there's 2 and not 20? This is specific to `components` which wasn't shown.

Comment: I added all of them to `page/index.vue`  and just the two first components that I've created in the first place appears. @EstusFlask